# R plot label with superscript as first character

Tags: r, plot, superscript

I am using R plots to plot isotopic data. I want to have an axis label with a superscript as the first character.
I have tried to do it the same way as for superscripts on the second caracter but get the following error

`x<-seq(0,10)
    y<-seq(0,10)
    plot(x, y,  ylab=expression(paste(^87,'Sr/',^'86','Sr')))`

Error: unexpected '^' in "plot(x, y,  ylab=expression(paste(^"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try an empty string at the start: `ylab=expression(text=''^87*'Sr/'^86*'Sr'))`

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndrewGustar You should post that as an answer so that future users can find it.

Answer (score 5):

The trick is to put an empty string at the start:

```
ylab=expression(text=''^87*'Sr/'^86*'Sr'))
```

Comment: In my case, I need to start the line with `^1` - superscript number, which works nicely with (`expression(""^1"), but in my case is not a solution, since I want to put the content of `text_in_var` and it seems the latter is not easy to do with `expression` - and easy with `bquote(.(text_in_var))`. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JelenaČuklina After some trial and error, I think `ylab=bquote(paste(""^1, .(text_in_var)))` might work.

Answer (score 0):

This command worked for me:

```
ylab(expression(~''^{"87"}~Sr/~''^{"86"}~Sr))
```